# unknown attribute: user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm getting the error unknown attribute: user_id durring execution of current_user.stories.build

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stories, class_name: 'Story', foreign_key: 'user_id', dependent: :destroy
  ...

class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  ...
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "stories", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "responsible"
    t.string   "descr"
    t.string   "state"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
    t.string   "name"
  end
```

It doesn't contain 'user_id' field. Any ideas?

Answer (score 29):

Kulbir is correct that you need to define a `user_id` column in your `stories` table, but doesn't explain the way to do that.

The correct way to make that change is to create a new migration. By convention, it should be called `add_user_id_to_stories` and would be created as follows (assuming you're using Rails 3+):

```
rails generate migration add_user_id_to_stories
```

If you run that, it should actually generate a migration that already contains the change you need to make, which should be something like:

```
add_column :stories, :user_id, :integer
```

As an aside when you're following the Rails conventions concerning association naming, which you are, you can actually skip a lot of the extra specification. In the `User` model, you can specify just `has_many :stories` and in the `Story` model specify `belongs_to :user`. Rails will assume the same class names and foreign keys you've specified.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a `user_id` field in your `stories` table like below to define the association in your models.

```
create_table "stories", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "responsible"
    t.string   "descr"
    t.string   "state"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end
  ...
end
```

**Edit**

Check Emily's answer for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the new syntax and pass the fieldtype as symbol

```
add_column :stories, :user_id, :integer
```