# NoMethodError (undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, nomethoderror, griddler

I'm very new to rails and was using the gem griddler to hopefully parse some incoming emails. I used all the code from the github site, and it provides an example emailprocessor.rb here:

```
class EmailProcessor
  def initialize(email)
    @email = email
  end

  def process
    //re-done with help from @Kris
    user = User.find_or_create_by(email: @email.from[:email]) do |u|
      u.email = @email.from[:email]
      u.name = @email.from[:name]
    end    


    user.posts.create!(
      subject: @email.subject,
      body: @email.body,

      attachment: @email.attachments,
      from: @email.from[:email]
    )
  end
end
```

I know i need to declare posts somehow and somewhere, but I have looked around on here and on the rails site and havent found anything to help me create it.  I get the error in the title when running heroku logs -t when the email server tries to post to the page.

here are the rest of my files that may be needed and what I've tried:

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
end
```

Post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

create_posts.rb

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :subject
      t.string :body
      t.string :from
      t.string :attachment

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @users = User.find(:all)
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        redirect_to :action => 'list'
    else
        render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

post_controller.rb

```
class PostController < ApplicationController


 def list
    @posts = Post.find(:all)
  end

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    if @post.save
        redirect_to :action => 'list'
    else
        @post = Subject.find(:all)
        render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

end
```

Any help is really appreciated, I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong so I can avoid it in the future

Comment: The error indicates that `user` is nil, which in turn suggests there is no user in the database for the given e-mail address. What do you want to happen when the user doesn't exist?

Comment: oh oops i feel dumb... i had been looking at posts this whole time but now that you say that that makes complete sense... if the user does not exist I would like to create a new user with that email, how would I go about doing that? @Kris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The e-mail address is not found in the database and therefor `user` is nil. You can create a user on the fly with the following code:

```
def process
  user = User.find_or_create_by(email: @email.from[:email]) do |u|
    # todo: set some other properties on the new user u, e.g. the name
  end

  user.posts.create!(
    subject: @email.subject,
    body: @email.body,      
    attachment: @email.attachments,
    from: @email.from[:email]
  )
end
```

See also [ActiveRecord::Relation::find_or_create_by](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by).

Comment: thanks man, was just about to post that the code I edited above fixed that problem, but now I am getting an error `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: user_id):`   `lib/email_processor.rb:16:in `process'`    I dont seem to have declared user_id anywhere?

Comment: What line is `email_processor.rb:16` ?

Comment: user.posts.create!(   ... and also thank you for the code you provided it is even simpler than what i have

Comment: When you have a `belongs_to` relation, your model needs to have a foreign key to the related model. Just add the user_id using a migration and it should work. See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529405/unknown-attribute-user-id

Comment: ahhh ok, makes sense! just tried it and that worked.  Thanks a ton for your help!